# AWS AppSync - Defining GraphQL schema with custom directives

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

While defining this custom directive:

`directive @hashField on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION`

I get this error on the AWS AppSync (Schema tab):

> Error parsing schema. Directive definitions are not supported.

I understand AWS provides [functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html#create-a-function) that can provide similar functionalities, but these functions won't work for my use case.

What's the alternative for custom directives in AWS AppSync? Is it going to be supported in a future release?

Comment: in the middle of 2023... nothing arise about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's not in their roadmap to add Directives support.

An alternative could be custom [scalar types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/); however, it doesn't meet my requirements since I need to specify order of multiple directives applied to a particular field.

Comment: Just a FYI, AWS AppSync does not support custom scalars...

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, using the AWS CDK, a Directive.custom method is available at both the field and object level e.g.

```
import { Field, GraphqlType, InterfaceType, ObjectType, Directive } from '@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha';

new ObjectType('MyObjectType', {
    definition: {
        id: GraphqlType.id({ isRequired: true }),
        name: new Field({ returnType: GraphqlType.string(), directives: [Directive.custom('@myCustomFieldDirective(param: "value")')] })
    },
    directives: [
        Directive.custom('@myCustomObjectDirective(param: "value")')
    ]
});
```